# Strong Wind(s) or High Wind(s)?

Tags: expressions, popularity

Which one is more popular?

I always used strong wind, but I found high winds also used some times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms *strong winds* and *high winds* are synonymous in everyday jargon, although they may have different meanings to a meteorologist.

As far as what phrase is more popular, I imagine it varies by locale. You can use Google Trends to analyze the popularity of two competing search terms. Here are [the results for *strong winds* and *high winds*](http://www.google.com/trends?q=high+winds%2C+strong+winds):

> - Worldwide, the two terms are used about as often, although *high winds* is a slightly more popular search term.
> - In the US, *high winds* is decidedly more popular than *strong winds*. This difference is most pronounced in North Dakota, Hawaii, and Nevada, where *high winds* trounces *strong winds*.
> - In other countries, such as New Zealand, Canada, and Australia, the term *strong winds* is quite a bit more popular a search term than *high winds*.
> - Some countries have virtually no one searching on the term *high winds*. The Philippines, Singapore, Finland, and Sweden are four such examples.

In a nutshell, both terms are valid, but which one is more popular depends on the region.

Answer (score 1):

The *CORPUS OF CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN ENGLISH* indicates that **high winds** is used more than **strong winds** (435 vs 251 occurrences).

Answer (score 0):

Either one is fine, although you do see "strong" used more. But it's your pleasure. Paul Simon repeats the phrase "strong wind" on his album *Graceland*. But the National Weather Service says on one of its pages "This information is most useful in the decision-making process to decide which people might be most vulnerable to high winds at inland locations."